# How to check if value of one column is in the array of another column in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
+------+--------------------+
|  col1|                col2|
+------+--------------------+
|  red |[red, yellow, pink] |
| blue |[blue, purple]      |
|green |[blue, purple]      |
+------+--------------------+
```

How could I figure out if the value in col1 is in the value of col2 using scala in Apache Spark?

I have tried using

```
array_contains(col("col2"), col("col1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using higher-order function [`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#exists):

```
val df = Seq(
  ("red", Seq("red", "yellow", "pink")),
  ("blue", Seq("blue", "purple")),
  ("green", Seq("blue", "purple"))
).toDF("item", "list")

df.withColumn("item_in_list", expr("exists(list, x -> x == item)")).show
// +-----+-------------------+------------+
// | item|               list|item_in_list|
// +-----+-------------------+------------+
// |  red|[red, yellow, pink]|        true|
// | blue|     [blue, purple]|        true|
// |green|     [blue, purple]|       false|
// +-----+-------------------+------------+
```

---

An alternative is to use [`array_except`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@last(columnName:String,ignoreNulls:Boolean):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) for array comparison:

```
df.withColumn("item_in_list", $"list" =!= array_except( $"list", array($"item"))).show
```

Note that `array_except` removes duplicates in the array.  If the array column consists of duplicates, [`array_distinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@last(columnName:String,ignoreNulls:Boolean):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) should be applied for the equality comparison.